# Javascript failing to load properly when in <head>

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Code is not working and I can't seem to figure out why. I have to keep the javascript in the html head because it is required and I believe that's where im going wrong and it's not loading properly.The window onload is something new for me and i'm not sure if that would be the correct way to use it

```
        ___Javascript___
        window.addEventListener("load", init);
       function validation(){
        var userNme = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var id = document.getElementById("student-id").value;
        var success = false;
        var words = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        


        if(userNme.match(words)){
            document.getElementsByClassName("one").setAttribute("class", "hidden");
            success = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("one").setAttribute("class", "visible"); 
        }

        if(pass.match(/[a-z]/) && pass.match(/[A-Z]/) && pass.match(/[0-9]/)){
            document.getElementsByClassName("two").setAttribute("class", "hidden");
            success = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("two").setAttribute("class", "visible"); 
        }

        if(id.length == 9){
            document.getElementsByClassName("three").setAttribute("class", "hidden"); 
            success = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("three").setAttribute("class", "visible"); 
        }

        
   }
         function init(){
        var start = document.getElementById("go");
        start.addEventListener("click", validation);
    }
         __HTML__ 
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    <div class="one hidden">
        Username needs to contain only letters
    </div>

    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="two hidden" id="Pword">
        Password needs to have at least one capital letter, one lower case, and one number
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="student-id" placeholder="Student id">
    <div class="three hidden">
        Student ID has to be exactly 9 numbers
    </div>

    <div class="four">
        <textarea id="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Enter text here" cols="22" rows="10" maxlength="25" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>
        <span style="color: red;" id="counter">25</span>
        <span style="color: black;">words remaining</span>
    </div>

    
        
            <input type="button" value="Submit" placeholder="Submit" id="go" onclick="init()" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because not all the elements are mounted on the DOM if `<script>` is in `<head>`. You use `<script>` in `<head>` when you want javascript to execute independent of the elements to be mounted.

If your `<script>` tag is trying to modify objects from `DOM`, you have to wait for the element to be mounted first.

Edited:

**Fix 1:**

Keep `<script>` tag below those elements. You can also use all these javascript on another file and then `<script src="path/to/js">` below all the elements that are used in the script.

**Fix 2:**

If you want to keep it in head, use `load` eventListener on `<body>` and then execute all these code. Instead of `window.addEventListener("load", init);` use `body.addEventListener("load", init)`.

Comment: What would be the correct way to fix this? by placing the script tags after the body?

Answer (score 0):

Saurav Pathak is correct, the expected format for inline JS would be something like this:

```
<head>
<script>
     // Some standard JS in here 
     // For readability I would but the event listeners at the end
     function validation(){
        var userNme = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var id = document.getElementById("student-id").value;
        var success = false;
        var words = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
        


        if(userNme.match(words)){
            document.getElementsByClassName("one").setAttribute("class", "hidden");
            success = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("one").setAttribute("class", "visible"); 
        }

        if(pass.match(/[a-z]/) && pass.match(/[A-Z]/) && pass.match(/[0-9]/)){
            document.getElementsByClassName("two").setAttribute("class", "hidden");
            success = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("two").setAttribute("class", "visible"); 
        }

        if(id.length == 9){
            document.getElementsByClassName("three").setAttribute("class", "hidden"); 
            success = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("three").setAttribute("class", "visible"); 
        }

        
       }
    function init(){
        var start = document.getElementById("go");
        start.addEventListener("click", validation);
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", init);
</script>
</head>
```

You can also place all you JS in a separate file and load is like this:
`<script src='/path/to/app.js'></script>`

The last thing of note is that sometimes you want the rest of the page to render before you get tags with JS. A lot of times you will put JS that depends on HTML elements to be rendered at the bottom of the HTML file (like in a `<footer>` tag).